# Input string was not in a correct format trace = Convert.ToDouble(tracedTemp) + trace

Tags: string, input

Good day,
Firsty, please understand I did not write this code, I am simply tring to fix an error as the orignal coder is no longer available.
Here is the code:

```
 tracedRecordsTemp = GR.Cells[1].Text;
            tracedTemp = GR.Cells[2].Text.Replace("R", "").Replace(",", ".").Replace("&#160;", "").Trim();
            completeRecordsTemp = GR.Cells[3].Text;
            completeTemp = GR.Cells[4].Text.Replace("R", "").Replace(",", ".").Replace("&#160;", "").Trim();
            bvCountTemp = GR.Cells[5].Text;
            bvPriceTemp = GR.Cells[6].Text.Replace("R", "").Replace(",", ".").Replace("&#160;", "").Trim();
            totalTemp = GR.Cells[7].Text.Replace("R", "").Replace(",", ".").Replace("&#160;", "").Trim();

            tracedRecords = Convert.ToInt16(tracedRecordsTemp) + tracedRecords;
            **trace = Convert.ToDouble(tracedTemp) + trace;**
            completeRecords = Convert.ToInt16(completeRecordsTemp) + completeRecords;
            complete = Convert.ToDouble(completeTemp) + complete;
            bvCount = Convert.ToInt16(bvCountTemp) + bvCount;
            bvPrice = Convert.ToDouble(bvPriceTemp) + bvPrice;
            total = Convert.ToDouble(totalTemp) + total;
```

The part in bold is causing the error. Could someone please advise on how to rectify this?
Thanking you.

Comment: I feel I need to add that this code is included in a webpage migrated from Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7 and it was working fine there. It is now on Server 2022 with IIS 10 and is throwing up this error. I did not code the webpages, I am simply trying to assist with the migration, I know nothing about ASP or coding. So if anyone can assist, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you it has been fixed.